# 'create-react-app' not work in another drive

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I m using window 10,I want to learn react but I stuck in a problem.
I use the following command `npm install -g create-react-app` and `create-react-app myapp` in c-drive
these command work properly but I run these command in other drive I got following error:

[image: Click to see]

my npm version is 6.14.15 and node version is 14.17.6
Anyone help me!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please include any code or errors as text instead of images, this makes it easier for other people to help you.

Comment: You should install npm and node on this drive also

Comment: Something weird going on there, especially with that second attempt. Try making sure you're using the latest CRA with `npx create-react-app@latest newApp`. Do you happen to have an `.npmrc` file in `G:/` or `G:/ReactJs`?

Comment: @Yosef.Schwartz there's no such thing as installing Node.js for a particular drive. You install it anywhere (eg `C:\Program Files`) and typically the `PATH` environment variable includes the binaries